# PhpStorm unable to structural replace

Tags: php, intellij-idea, phpstorm, structural-search

How do I structural replace with PhpStorm?

I am trying to update the obsolete `mysql_` functions with the new `mysqli` class.

My Search Template:

```
$row$ = mysql_fetch_array($query$)
```

My Replacement template:

```
$row$ = $query$->fetch_array()
```

Giving me back the

> Error "Unsopported replacement pattern.."

Changing my search template to

```
$row$ = mysql_fetch_array($query$))
```

strangely solved the problem. Giving me this

`No template '$dates$ = mysql_fetch_array($quere$))' found in All Places`

Can somebody explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @Xorifelse Seems like this question is actually meant to replace `mysql_` calls with `mysqli` library calls (I would recommend PDO, but afaik mysqli won't get deprecated soon).

Comment: @Jeto Silly me, you are correct. Thing is I make it a policy to not answer any questions related to `mysql_` and when I saw that line of code I didn't read the rest of the question :o

Comment: While @Jeto corrected me, I did not expect an "automation" on fixing "legacy" code. **AND NOOR SHOULD YOU DO IT**. There is no point in doing this because vulnerability from injection is copied right from `mysql` to the `mysqli` library. There is no point in doing it, just stick with PHP 6 if you're too lazy to actually code.

Answer (score 3):

You're not putting a semicolon at the end of the statement.

In fact, Structural Search and Replace has been broken in PhpStorm for years, but right now there's a lot of work being done to fix that, and your particular case works nice in 2018.1.2: http://recordit.co/pQubl3VSGd

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest simply using regular expressions search & replace for this:

**Search**:

```
mysql_fetch_array\((\$\w+?)\)
```

**Replace:**

```
$1->fetch_array()
```